# How to set the AJP packet size in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, ajp

I've followed the instructions here for setting the maxPacketSize in AJP...

[AJP connector doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html)

It states in the doc that I need to "you must also change the packetSize attribute of your AJP connector on the Tomcat side! The attribute packetSize is only available in Tomcat 5.5.20+ and 6.0.2+."

I have no idea how to change it though!

This doc talks about changing it in Tomcat, but I can't find out WHERE I actually need to change it (what properties file/config file etc)

[Tomcat AJP Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/ajp.html)

Can anyone give me a clue please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what I was looking for was where to change it.

in the end it was simple, it was in...

```
C:\Tomcat\conf\server.xml
```

Change...

```
<!-- Define a Coyote/JK2 AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009"
enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" debug="0"
protocol="AJP/1.3" />
```

to

```
<!-- Define a Coyote/JK2 AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009"
enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" debug="0" packetSize=21000
protocol="AJP/1.3" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It's right there on the second link ("Tomcat AJP Connector") under "packetSize"