# tomcat + servlet: buffer error while write cookie

Tags: tomcat, servlets, cookies

i have a servlet that retrieve some data from database, write result into cookie and sent it to client. 
But while i'm debugging my code, i've occours in a strange error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [StoricoAcquisti] in context with path [/Serv] threw exception
org.apache.coyote.http11.HeadersTooLargeException: An attempt was made to write more data to the response headers than there was room available in the buffer. Increase maxHttpHeaderSize on the connector or write less data into the response headers.
```

How can i fix it? should i write much more than a cookie if data overflow ?

Comment: See this link :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837505/setting-max-http-header-size-with-ajp-tomcat-6-0

Comment: I believe you missed the point of cookies. Those are not intented as complete data storage containers, but they are intented to hold unique keys/identifiers referencing the desired data in the real data storage container (e.g. server's memory, server's DB, etc). What exactly is it, the concrete functional requirement for which you thought that this would be the right solution? If you elaborate that instead, then we may come up with the right solution to that.